# Ввод структур с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

```
int quantityOfStructs;
    cin >> quantityOfStructs;
    vector<RouteInfo>route;
    route.reserve(quantityOfStructs);
    for (int i = 0; i < quantityOfStructs; i++) {
        RouteInfo routeN;
        cin >> routeN;
        route[i]=routeN;

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantityOfStructs; i++) {
        cout << route[i] << endl;
    }
```

Мне надо записать структуру RouteInfo с клавиатуры quantityOfStructs раз в вектор. Вектор все время выдаёт ошибку out of range.

P.S. операторы перегружены

Answer (score 3):

```
route.resize(quantityOfStructs);
```

Разнице между `reserve` и `resize` ощущаете? :)